# Is there a way to group matrix elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am working on a problem which requires me to group array elements and average each group. For example consider the 4 x 4 matrix M,

```
M = [ 1 0 0 1;
      1 0 1 1;
      1 1 0 1;
      0 0 0 1;]
```

I want to group this into a 2 x 2 matrix, taking an average of the elements so we would get

```
M1 = [0.5 0.75;
      0.5 0.5;]
```

does anyone know a way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: There are answers for your question. Please select one as the correct answer to your problem, if they do what you are trying to achieve. If they are not what you are looking for, please add some additional information about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html), and a little indexing, like so:

```
>> A = conv2(M,ones(2), 'same');
>> A(1:2:end,1:2:end)/4

ans =

    0.5000    0.7500
    0.5000    0.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to first split your matrix in parts using mat2cell, then apply your functions to each part and merge them to a new matrix:

```matlab
>> M = [ 1 0 0 1;
1 0 1 1;
1 1 0 1;
0 0 0 1;]

M =

     1     0     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1
     0     0     0     1

>> T=mat2cell(M, [2 2], [2 2])

T =

  2×2 cell array

    {2×2 double}    {2×2 double}
    {2×2 double}    {2×2 double}

>> M1 = cellfun(@mean, cellfun(@mean, T, 'UniformOutput', false))

M1 =

    0.5000    0.7500
    0.5000    0.5000

>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for any rectangle, where x and y denote the size of domains that you want to average.

```
function M1 = get_means(M, x, y) 
    [rows, cols] = size(M);
    if mod(rows, x) == 0 && mod(cols, y) == 0
        for i = 1:y:cols
            for j = 1:x:rows
                M1((j+x-1)/x, (i+y-1)/y) = sum(M(j:j+x-1,i:i+y-1),'all')/(x*y);
            end
        end
    else
        error('The matrix doesn''t have compatible dimensions.')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the grouped matrices and then calculate the mean

```
M = [ 1 0 0 1;
      1 0 1 1;
      1 1 0 1;
      0 0 0 1;];

n=2; % 2x2 mat
 
% create new matrix with means
MM = zeros(n,n);
 
% row counter for mean-Matrix
r=1;

% loop over matrix groups
for row=1:n:size(M,1)
    c = 1; % column counter for mean-Matrix
    for col=1:n:size(M,2)
        MM(r,c) = mean(mean(M(row:row+n-1, col:col+n-1)));
        c = c+1;
    end
    r = r+1;
end
```

Output:

```
MM =

0.5000    0.7500
0.5000    0.5000
```